# Differences between action and actionListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, action, actionlistener

What is the difference between `action` and `actionListener`, and when should I use `action` versus `actionListener`?

Answer (score 620, accepted):

### actionListener

Use `actionListener` if you want have a hook **before** the real business action get executed, e.g. to log it, and/or to set an additional property (by [`<f:setPropertyActionListener>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html)), and/or to have access to the component which invoked the action (which is available by [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/ActionEvent.html) argument). So, purely for preparing purposes before the real business action gets invoked.

The `actionListener` method has by default the following signature:

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
// ...

public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

And it's supposed to be declared as follows, without any method parentheses:

```
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.actionListener}" />
```

Note that you can't pass *additional* arguments by EL 2.2. You can however override the `ActionEvent` argument altogether by passing and specifying custom argument(s). The following examples are valid:

```
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.methodWithoutArguments()}" />
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.methodWithOneArgument(arg1)}" />
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.methodWithTwoArguments(arg1, arg2)}" />
```

```
public void methodWithoutArguments() {}
public void methodWithOneArgument(Object arg1) {}
public void methodWithTwoArguments(Object arg1, Object arg2) {}
```

Note the importance of the parentheses in the argumentless method expression. If they were absent, JSF would still expect a method with `ActionEvent` argument.

If you're on EL 2.2+, then you can declare multiple action listener methods via `<f:actionListener binding>`.

```
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.actionListener1}">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.actionListener2()}" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.actionListener3()}" />
</h:commandXxx>
```

```
public void actionListener1(ActionEvent event) {}
public void actionListener2() {}
public void actionListener3() {}
```

Note the importance of the parentheses in the `binding` attribute. If they were absent, EL would confusingly throw a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'actionListener1' not found on type com.example.Bean`, because the `binding` attribute is by default interpreted as a value expression, not as a method expression. Adding EL 2.2+ style parentheses transparently turns a value expression into a method expression. See also a.o. [Why am I able to bind <f:actionListener> to an arbitrary method if it's not supported by JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744949/why-am-i-able-to-bind-factionlistener-to-an-arbitrary-method-if-its-not-supp)

---

### action

Use `action` if you want to execute a business action and if necessary handle navigation. The `action` method can (thus, not must) return a `String` which will be used as navigation case outcome (the target view). A return value of `null` or `void` will let it return to the same page and keep the current view scope alive. A return value of an empty string or the same view ID will also return to the same page, but recreate the view scope and thus destroy any currently active view scoped beans and, if applicable, recreate them.

The `action` method can be any valid [`MethodExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html), also the ones which uses EL 2.2 arguments such as below:

```html
<h:commandXxx value="submit" action="#{bean.edit(item)}" />
```

With this method:

```
public void edit(Item item) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that when your action method solely returns a string, then you can also just specify exactly that string in the `action` attribute. Thus, this is totally clumsy:

```html
<h:commandLink value="Go to next page" action="#{bean.goToNextpage}" />
```

With this senseless method returning a hardcoded string:

```
public String goToNextpage() {
    return "nextpage";
}
```

Instead, just put that hardcoded string directly in the attribute:

```html
<h:commandLink value="Go to next page" action="nextpage" />
```

Please note that this in turn indicates a bad design: navigating by POST. This is not user nor SEO friendly. This all is explained in [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723) and is supposed to be solved as

```html
<h:link value="Go to next page" outcome="nextpage" />
```

See also [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o).

---

### f:ajax listener

Since JSF 2.x there's a third way, the `<f:ajax listener>`.

```
<h:commandXxx ...>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.ajaxListener}" />
</h:commandXxx>
```

The `ajaxListener` method has by default the following signature:

```
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
// ...

public void ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

In Mojarra, the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` argument is optional, below works as good.

```
public void ajaxListener() {
    // ...
}
```

But in MyFaces, it would throw a `MethodNotFoundException`. Below works in both JSF implementations when you want to omit the argument.

```
<h:commandXxx ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{bean.ajaxListener()}" render="@form" />
</h:commandXxx>
```

Ajax listeners are not really useful on command components. They are more useful on input and select components `<h:inputXxx>`/`<h:selectXxx>`. In command components, just stick to `action` and/or `actionListener` for clarity and better self-documenting code. Moreover, like `actionListener`, the `f:ajax listener` does not support returning a navigation outcome.

```
<h:commandXxx ... action="#{bean.action}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandXxx>
```

For explanation on `execute` and `render` attributes, head to [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes).

---

### Invocation order

The `actionListener`s are always invoked *before* the `action` in the same order as they are been declared in the view and attached to the component. The `f:ajax listener` is always invoked *before* any action listener. So, the following example:

```html
<h:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{bean.actionListener}" action="#{bean.action}">
    <f:actionListener type="com.example.ActionListenerType" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.actionListenerBinding()}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.property}" value="some" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.ajaxListener}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Will invoke the methods in the following order:

1. `Bean#ajaxListener()`
2. `Bean#actionListener()`
3. `ActionListenerType#processAction()`
4. `Bean#actionListenerBinding()`
5. `Bean#setProperty()`
6. `Bean#action()`

---

### Exception handling

The `actionListener` supports a special exception: [`AbortProcessingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/AbortProcessingException.html). If this exception is thrown from an `actionListener` method, then JSF will skip any remaining action listeners and the action method and proceed to render response directly. You won't see an error/exception page, JSF will however log it. This will also implicitly be done whenever any other exception is being thrown from an `actionListener`. So, if you intend to block the page by an error page as result of a business exception, then you should definitely be performing the job in the `action` method.

If the sole reason to use an `actionListener` is to have a `void` method returning to the same page, then that's a bad one. The `action` methods can perfectly also return `void`, on the contrary to what some IDEs let you believe via EL validation. Note that the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) examples are littered with this kind of `actionListener`s over all place. This is indeed wrong. Don't use this as an excuse to also do that yourself.

In ajax requests, however, a special exception handler is needed. This is regardless of whether you use `listener` attribute of `<f:ajax>` or not. For explanation and an example, head to [Exception handling in JSF ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests).

Comment: You're right that exceptions in actionListeners are swallowed by default, but in JSF 2.0 this behavior can be altered. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @arjan: you're right that JSF 2.0 allows you to change the default handling of exceptions thrown by `actionListener`, but that still doesn't make it a good excuse to abuse `actionListener` for **business** actions.

Comment: Indeed, business actions are in the main "flow" of the request/response cycle and only the `action` corresponds with that. `actionListener` is for secondary stuff. Just wanted to clarify that exceptions from `actionListener`s can be propagated if so required ;)

Comment: Hi BalusC, I try to confirm your answer by writing some code, but the result is a bit odd. Will you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683211/jsf2-action-and-actionlistener?

Comment: Note that the class name action listener signature is `void processAction(ActionEvent event)`.

Comment: @Kawy: the method name is free to choice when used in `actionListener` attribute and it has to be `public` as well. The `processAction` name is only mandatory when you're using `<f:actionListener type>`, simply because the type has to implement `ActionListener` interface which has exactly that method name `processAction` definied.

Comment: Yes, by "class name action listener" I meant the `<f:actionListener>` tag (without the void).

Comment: @BalusC , may I ask, what would the order of execution be if there's a nested f:ajax with a listener attribute, how would the execution flow go?

Comment: @Muhammed: ajax action listener is invoked before all regular action listeners. Note that even when using `<f:ajax>`, you'd in case of command components prefer using the `action` attribute for business actions. E.g. `<h:commandButton action="#{bean.businessAction}"><f:ajax/></h:commandButton>`.

Comment: This `<h:link value="Go to next page" outcome="nextpage" />` just won't work in PrimeFaces. `<h:outputLink` works

Comment: @Vlad: that problem is caused elsewhere and completely unrelated to the current Q&A. I believe you intended to post that comment on a different post.

Comment: @BalusC: The problem that I mentioned actually happens inside a `<p:treeTable>`, in Liferay. Could be related to that. Thanks.

Comment: @BalusC: returning a null value from an action method loses the request parameters. Could you please explain how can they be kept in these circumstances? Thanks!

Comment: @Neil: That's likely a misobservation. Same problem will occur when returning non-null. Head on to http://stackoverflow.com/q/17734230.

Comment: @BalusC: I'd found that too but was wanting to distinguish between returning null and using void. The post you referenced was for redirecting to another page. If the action needs to return to the same page after a validation failure, how is that best done in order to keep the parameters but not call the PostConstruct method which in my case will reinitialise all the values?

Comment: @BalusC In the invocation order can we say that the `disabled` condition is re evaluated before everything else (before 1) and might prevent running everything else?  If so, is that a standard?

Comment: @ForguesR: yes but this happens during an earlier phase already, the apply request values phase. See also point 6 of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656

Answer (score 48):

As BalusC indicated, the `actionListener` by default swallows exceptions, but in JSF 2.0 there is a little more to this. Namely, it doesn't just swallows and logs, but actually **publishes** the exception.

This happens through a call like this:

```
context.getApplication().publishEvent(context, ExceptionQueuedEvent.class,                                                          
    new ExceptionQueuedEventContext(context, exception, source, phaseId)
);
```

The default listener for this event is the `ExceptionHandler` which for Mojarra is set to `com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl`. This implementation will basically rethrow any exception, except when it concerns an AbortProcessingException, which is logged. ActionListeners wrap the exception that is thrown by the client code in such an AbortProcessingException which explains why these are always logged.

This `ExceptionHandler` can be replaced however in faces-config.xml with a custom implementation:

```
<exception-handlerfactory>
   com.foo.myExceptionHandler
</exception-handlerfactory>
```

Instead of listening globally, a single bean can also listen to these events. The following is a proof of concept of this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

    public void actionMethod(ActionEvent event) {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().subscribeToEvent(ExceptionQueuedEvent.class, new SystemEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext content = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext)event.getSource();
            throw new RuntimeException(content.getException());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
            return true;
        }
        });

        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

}
```

*(note, this is not how one should normally code listeners, this is only for demonstration purposes!)*

Calling this from a Facelet like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="test" actionListener="#{myBean.actionMethod}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Will result in an error page being displayed.

Answer (score 44):

**ActionListener gets fired first, with an option to modify the response, before Action gets called and determines the location of the next page.**

If you have multiple buttons on the same page which should go to the same place but do slightly different things, you can use the same Action for each button, but use a different ActionListener to handle slightly different functionality.

Here is a link that describes the relationship:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=605

Comment: plus one, The bold letters says almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**:

The `ActionListener`s (there can be multiple) execute in the order they were registered BEFORE the `action`

**Long Answer**:

A business `action` typically invokes an EJB service and if necessary also sets the final result and/or navigates to a different view
if that is not what you are doing an `actionListener` is more appropriate i.e. for when the user interacts with the components, such as `h:commandButton` or `h:link` they can be handled by passing the name of the managed bean method in `actionListener` attribute of a UI Component or to implement an `ActionListener` interface and pass the implementation class name to `actionListener` attribute of a UI Component.